# Solving the quartic polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, quartics

I have three quartic polynomials:
$$1)\  x^4-(1+r+s+rs)x^2-2rsx+rs=0, s\geq  r\geq 1,$$
$$2)\ x^4-(2q+qs+s)x^2-2qsx+qs=0,q\geq 2, s\geq 1,$$
$$3)\ x^4-(6+4s)x^2-8sx+4s=0,s\geq 2.$$
$q,r,$ and $s$ are positive integers. Also, I have for any $\varepsilon>0$ and $n\geq 4$, $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$:
$$2n-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}< x_1 < 2n+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2},$$
$$0<x_2\leq \sqrt{2}-1,$$
$$-n-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}< x_3< -n+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
$$-n-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<x_4< -n+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}+\frac{\varepsilon}{4}$$
Suppose $x_2$ is a root of these equations. I want to prove other $x_i$'s can't be the roots of the above each quartic equations. I know  $x_i$'s are real. I start with the easiest equation, third one. I studied the methods and  I tried to obtain the roots but
I was confused. Then I try to get some contradictions by the conditions of $x_i$'s and Vieta's formula, but I couldn't. Also I used the rational root theorem and I found the third equation dose not have the rational roots. If $x_i$'s make you confused, you can ignore them and help me how to solve the equations.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: The $3^{rd}$ equation always has a root in $(0, \sqrt{2}-1)$ so you cannot exclude $x_2$.

Comment: All of these equations has this root,  I know this (there is a famous theorem by petrovic'). But we should notice to other roots. All of them with the conditions can't be the roots of these equations.

Comment: You should clarify in the question whether you mean that none of the $x_k$ can be a root vs. not all of $4$ of them can be the roots of each polynomial. As for the last one, it must have a real root in $(0, \sqrt{2}-1)$ because $P_3(0) \gt 0 \gt P_3(\sqrt{2}-1)\,$.

Comment: You're right. I edited.